# Can a child_process which was forked be a parent and fork new processes as well?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

In my Electron app's user interface (UI), there is a button which when clicked, uses [child_process.fork()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options) to spin up another script. This new child communicates status messages using [process.send()](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback) to update the UI on the progress. *This all works great*.

In the child process however, there comes a point when its time to do some work in parallel (Stage6). In Stage6 I use the same child_process.fork() method to launch 8 workers. Debug messages indicate that these 8 workers do indeed fork just fine; I keep a reference to them in an array and all seems well.

The problem is, that once these 8 workers are forked, *I never hear from them again*. Their messages sent using process.send() are never received by Stage6. Its like they don't exist.

Now, here's the fun part! **OUTSIDE** of Electron I created a test script (using Node on the CLI) to launch those 8 workers *in exactly the same way that Stage6 does*, and they work just fine and the test script hears their messages. So the issue isn't with the workers, it seems to be how they are launched.

**In Electron, can a process which was itself forked (from a UI in my case) be a "parent" as well and fork children? Can we fork inside a fork? Or is that just too forking much?**

Comment: Can you give some example code please? For debugging purposes. Generally speaking this *should* work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes, a child_process can also be a "parent" and fork another child_process**. OP's problem must be elsewhere. Consider these three files:

**1.js**

```
const cp = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");

console.log(`[f1] 1 has started; now forking 2...`);

let f2 = cp.fork(path.normalize(`${__dirname}\\2`));

f2.on("message", (message) => {
  console.log(`[f2] ${message}`);
});

f2.on("exit", () => {
  console.log(`[f1] f2 just exited, so 1 is too.`);
});
```

**2.js**

```
const cp = require("child_process");
const path = require("path");

process.send(`This is 2 starting up; now forking 3`);

let f3 = cp.fork(path.normalize(`${__dirname}\\3`));

f3.on("message", (message) => {
  console.log(`[f3] ${message}`);
});

f3.on("exit", () => {
  console.log(`[f2] f3 just exited, so I am too.`);
  process.exit();
});
```

**3.js**

```
process.send(`This is 3 starting up, and now shutting down`);
process.exit();
```

Running "node 1.js" produces the following output, which proves that 2.js can be both a child process of 1.js as well as the parent of 3.js

```
[f1] 1 has started; now forking 2...
[f2] This is 2 starting up; now forking 3
[f3] This is 3 starting up, and now shutting down
[f2] f3 just exited, so I am too.
[f1] f2 just exited, so 1 is too.
```

Comment: This example code was written in straight Node, but moving it into the Electron environment posed no differences. It works fine in Electron too, so I will remove the Electron tag and mark this as the answer.